# VBA For Loop stopping early

Tags: excel, vba

I wanted to pass through the loop 100 times and stop when a is 101 then go to the next line. However, when it reached 101 the code just stops and does go to the next line. If the for loop is from 1 to 10 is goes to the next line without a problem, but it seems like anything greater than 10 is won't go to the next line.

```
Function fint(x As Double) As Double
Dim a As Double, b As Double, c As Double, d As Double, e As Double
Dim sum As Variant, sum1 As Variant, sum2 As Variant, sum3 As Variant
Dim group As Double, group1 As Double, group2 As Double

sum = 0
sum1 = 0
sum2 = 0
sum3 = 0

For a = 0 To 100

sum = sum + (x / 2) ^ (2 * a) / ((WorksheetFunction.Fact(a)) ^ 2 * (2 * a + 1))

Next a

group = -1 * (0.5772156649 * WorksheetFunction.Ln(x / 2)) * x * sum

fint = group

End Function
```

[image]

Comment: Try `Dim group As Decimal`

Comment: `0 to 100` is 101

Comment: @PuravTheGreat How do I do that? I tried in vba, but i could not do it as Decimal.

Comment: @Rain yeh nvm I read somewhere you could set the variable as a `Decimal` but you can't, best you can do is `Double` but that's not working for you...

Comment: @PuravTheGreat Yeah for some reason it is not working. Is there some kind of limit that once it reaches 100 and above it will just randomly stop for the for loop?

Comment: `Double` has a range of "-1.79769313486232e+308 to -4.94065645841247E-324 for negative values 4.94065645841247E-324 to 1.79769313486232e+308 for positive values."

Comment: Try with 20, 30, 40 ... etc until it stops working - that may be the most exact value you could get?

Comment: @PuravTheGreat I will do that thank you

Comment: Lemme know when it stops, I'm interested

Comment: I tested your code, `fint(1)` errors out (Overflow) at a=99 (it's the `.Fact(99)^2` that causes the overflow).

Comment: @PuravTheGreat You cannot `Dim x As Decimal` but you can `Dim x As Variant: CDec(x)` to get a `Decimal`

Comment: Oooh could that solve the issue?